How to determine GPU encoder and decoder utilization of a past process?
Is there a way to query encoder and decoder utilization for a completed process?
nvmlDeviceGetAccountingStats only returns GPU core and memory statistics.
nvmlDeviceGetProcessUtilization returns decUtil and encUtil, but only works for running processes.
